# Android HTML5 image load never complete

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am using Android WebView to load a local image from device. But load never complete.
This is my HTML code:

```
            var image = new Image();
            image.onLoad = function(){
                Android.log("image loaded");
            }
            image.onerror = function(){
                Android.log("error loading url");
            }
            image.src = url;

            Android.log("Start loading");
```

Android is an object that I defined to communicate with the native app.
I am getting the "Start loading" log. But no errors and no onLoad is called.

This is the url I am loading: `file:/data/data/my.package.name/tmp_ime.jpg`

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you append the image to the document?

Comment: @L.Monty no, I did not

Comment: Also doesnt work "file://data/data/my.package.name/tmp_ime.jpg"?

Comment: Try "file:///data/data/my.package.name/tmp_ime.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

I love Java script! This is the solution for my problem:

Change:

```
image.onLoad
```

To

```
image.onload
```

Small 'L'